# Unknown system error -86 Electron app packaging on Mac for Window using electron-packager

Tags: electron, packager

Thank you in advance for helping. I am following this tutorial to build an electron app, https://coursetro.com/courses/22/Creating-Desktop-Apps-with-Electron-Tutorial

I am at the last stage which is to package it from a Mac M1 chip for Windows.

Here is what's happening in my terminal.

home@Homes-Mac-mini crypto-app % electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds

Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v13.1.1

spawn Unknown system error -86

home@Homes-Mac-mini crypto-app %

Really appreciate any help!

Thank you all.

Comment: While I can't provide an answer to your question, I wanted to note that you should never ever post images of code or exception messages instead of actual text. Thus, I would like to ask you to [edit] your question to paste in the error message as text. Thanks!

Comment: Noted. Thank you! I have edited.